What did Jesus mean in the gospels of Mathew and John respectively?
Mathew 16:28

Truly, I say to you, there are some standing here who will not taste death until they see the Son of Man coming in his kingdom.

John 21:22

If it is my will that he remain until I come, what is that to you?

Did Jesus mean these folks would not die until they see him coming in his kingdom(which I interpret to mean his second coming)?

@Jason_, my question has linked the verse in the book of John which exposed the intent by Jesus for some men to remain alive until he returns. The post you link doesn't and seeks the correct interpretation of the same verse in different gospels

The weight of evidence is very strong in regard to the orthodox teaching - that the transfiguration is in view, not the second comig.

@NigelJ, no one knows if some men have remained since Jesus stepped foot on this earth. Only God knows if they are among us.

No, I disagree. We would be told if that were so. And it would not be a righteous thing, were it so. The righteousness of God requires satisfaction in the judgment of sin and death. Your suggestion would contradict how God has done that.
